# Complete site redirection to sub-domain using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've searched all over the internet, finding multiple answers to achieve a redirect, but none have ever been 100% full-proof. I need a .htaccess subdomain redirect that works **in every circumstance**:

- "protocol://mysite.com/" → "protocol://subdomain.mysite.com/"
- "protocol://www.mysite.com/" → "protocol://subdomain.mysite.com/"
- "protocol://mysite.com/folder/" → "protocol://subdomain.mysite.com/folder/"
- "protocol://www.mysite.com/folder/" → "protocol://subdomain.mysite.com/folder/"

I know it's possible, but I can't find any good documentation on it, let alone documentation on the .htaccess fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (placing as the first rule on  your .htaccess Rewrite section

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain.yourdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://subdomain.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**note** remember changing both subdomain.yourdomain.com to your desired subdomain url and restart apache.

**note 2** Change to https:// if your desired destination is also a https domain

**note 3** for TEMPORARY redirects, change "R=301" to "R=302"

**EDIT** some helpfull links about apache .htaccess

http://www.tecmint.com/apache-htaccess-tricks/
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Doesn't work any way I try, best I could get was subdomain.mainsite.com/subdomain/subdomain/subdomain/subdomain/subdomain/ are you sure you typed it correctly?

Comment: do you have more rules after this one?? place this one on the first place and add the L flag (i´m making a change right now to show)

Comment: Pasted in what you wrote, redirects to your.subdomain.com

Comment: And what do you need ? Is not that?

Comment: @JoshuaSandoval You need to replace `your.subdomain.com` with the actual subdomain you want to redirect to...

Comment: I think you need to change it to your desired subdomain url... It,s suposed that subdomain is fixed..... Right?

Comment: I got it working, had to reset my cache a million time though.

Comment: :) nice!!! I'll make an edit to the answer to advice changing to your desired domain

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain.yourdomain.com$ RewriteRule ^(.*) http://subdomain.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301]

Comment: Ok!! Changing to clarify

Comment: do I change "HTTP" to "HTTPS" for https connections?

Comment: You just need for that when the user must go over the https protocol (if you change it, the user'll go to the https url).

Comment: Nevermind. @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz You should put a notice for "https" change "http" to "https".

Comment: …whatever, we'll figure it out.